# Commands like CREATE, GRANT, DROP always return "0 rows affected"

Tags: mysql

I was considering why some special commands in mysql like `create user`, `grant privileges`, `drop user` when correct passed return `"0 rows affected"`, which is not true! (rows in mysql db are affected indeed)

I know there are not standard queries, but if we do `delete from user where ...` on `mysql` database, we will see `N rows affected`.

so it's countable in rather easy way.
otherwise response "Query OK (0.00 sec)" will be much accurate.

or am I missing sth?
I verify above with a few mysql version 5.1-5.5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way mysql works is this ...

Performing INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs explicitly names tables

SQL Commands that do not explicitly name tables have `0 row(s) affected`

Such commands that echo `0 row(s) affected` include

- CREATE USER
- GRANT/REVOKE
- CHANGE MASTER TO (to Setup MySQL Replication)

I suppose this has always been the case.

Comment: Link to support answer : http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64313 & http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html

Comment: well, what if I create table or insert record or alter table or something? It returns always 0.

Answer (score 1):

You're right it's a little bit confusing but it's not a bug. See MySQL Documentation for the [**TRUNCATE command**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/truncate-table.html):

> Truncation operations do not return a meaningful value for the number
>   of deleted rows. The usual result is “0 rows affected,” which should
>   be interpreted as "no information".

Max.

Comment: This is actually a problem of the SQL client rather than "MySQL" itself. Not all clients behave this way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the clarification. Is there a better SQL client you can suggest for using with MySQL on Windows?